# Git cancel everything made today

Tags: git, github

I wanted to do a `git rebase`, but I canceled it because I needed to check something first. Somehow I messed up my Git history.

I tried to cancel that using `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}` (after checking with `git reflog`, but it didn't work, so I decided to google it and I followed the instructions:

1. `git fetch origin master`
2. `git checkout -f master origin/master`

The command failed so I didn't go further. Now my git history is even more messed up and I have no idea how to fix it. I just want to get back to work.

How do I go back to how it was 2h ago?

Comment: "didn't work" and "the command failed" do not help us in helping you. provide more information. what errors are you seeing?

Comment: The question is "how do i go back to how it was 2h ago"
if i can't do that then i'll just delete the repo and create a new one.

Comment: Yeah, we understand what you want. But we don't know how your attempt failed, because our collective crystal ball is currently under repair (thanks, Dave!).

Comment: "i'll just delete the repo and create a new one" https://xkcd.com/1597/ This is actually an easy solution to comprehend and execute, so not a bad suggestion, as long as you don't have any work you want to save.

Comment: Well the git reset didn't change anything
and the git checkout said origin/master doesn't exist, and yes the branch name is master

Comment: `git reset --hard @{two.hours.ago}`. If that’s what you really want.

Comment: +1 on the "provide more information". Example information: what command did you run to cancel the rebase ? what "didn't work" with `git reset --hard` : did the command produce an error ? is your active commit not the one you named on the command line ?

Comment: you mention in a comment: "git checkout said origin/master doesn't exist", which looks weird. If you had pasted the *error message*, it would have been: `error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git`, which says that the *file* origin/master doesn't exist (that one is probably less surprising). That's because `-f` isn't the option you are looking for: you probably want `git checkout -B master origin/master`

Comment: git interface is certainly clunky, and I sympathize to the frustration you may feel when trying to do sth with it. The tone and the content of your question, however, currently make it a poor fit for this QA website (it is unlikely to help other people looking for answers). Can you please: either edit your question to provide relevant content, or delete your question entirely ?

Comment: Please avoid profanity.

Answer (score 1):

While `git reset --hard` **might** get you back to where you want to be notice that this is a "destructive" command that potentially makes you lose stuff you want. It is a command that should be treated with great respect and only used when strictly necessary.

I would suggest a different approach. Take the reflog and just create some temporary tags for the latest N entries, and then examine them and find then one that actually matches what you want. This is a non-destructive approach that leaves you the option to check out any of the potential candidates and verify.

To examine the last 20 ref-log entries run

```bash
git reflog | head -20 | sort -u | awk '{print "git tag reflog-tag-" $1 " " $1}' | bash
# E.g.
# git tag reflog-tag-0defc84 0defc84
# git tag reflog-tag-2100d5e 2100d5e
# git tag reflog-tag-287e250 287e250
# ...
```

and then start `gitk --all &` to look at the commits.

---

When you have found the commit that is the tip of where you want your branch to be, then you can run a hard reset against that commit. To remove all the temporary reflog tags run `git tag -l | grep ^reflog-tag- | xargs git tag -d`.

Comment: Actually an easier way is to run `gitk --reflog` which shows all reflog entries directly.